# Hide div for set period after clicking on button

Tags: jquery, cookies

I got a float button that you can close. Here is the code of that button :

```
   <div class="primary"><button id="ferme" class="popup-button" data-modal="popup">Deviens un Lhibou</button><div class="alert-close"></div></div>
```

Here is the Jquery code that makes the close button deleting the whole div :

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(c) {
    $('#alert-close').on('click', function(c){
        $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow', function(c){
        });
    }); 
});
})(jQuery);
```

My question is : how could I set cookies that would hide the div for set period after clicking on button ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use setTimeout to solve your problem

Comment: Right now your code has a problem. You are using an id selector for calling the click event, but the div has a class with that name.

Comment: setTimeout will solve your problem easily, but if the user refreshes the page, the div will become visible again. If you want the div to be hidden certain amount of time even if the page refreshes you have to use cookies. So, which alternative do you need?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now, it works nice because the whole div #primary disappear but I want it not appear when the page is refresh. So I would need the cookie solution, but I dont know how to implement it in my Jquery code...